# How to Copy HTML of Active Page in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension, in that app I want to copy the HTML of third party website for content scraping purposes. I am using following JQuery function for this,

```
$(".abc").clone().html();
```

It works good in simple HTML page, but doesn't when I use it in the popup.js file of the extension.

How can I copy the HTML of the webpage in Chrome Extension?

My manifest.json file is

```
{
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WGCE",
  "version": "1.0",
  // Recommended
  "description": "App Description",
  // Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["popup.js"],
    "matches": ["https://example.com/*"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Don't use popup.js in a content script. The popup is a totally different page, not connected to the web page. It has its own DOM (document, window, and so on), and its own devtools which you can open by rightclicking the popup, then 'inspect'. Make sure to read the extension overview in the documentation.

Comment: Use a content script to grab and pass the data to background script.